# Как сделать активный якорь при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается при скролле менять активные якорные ссылки.
в js не силен, но кое что все таки сделал изменение класса при клике, но остальное вместе с этими скриптами не получается.

```js
$(".nav-menu ul li").click(function(e) {
  $(".nav-menu ul li").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(".nav-menu").on("click", "a", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();


  var id = $(this).attr('href'),


    top = $(id).offset().top;

  $(body, html).animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul class="dot-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-b1" class="active">
        <span>Boards</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-b2" class="">
        <span>Boards</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-b3" class="">
        <span>Boards</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-b4" class="">
        <span>Boards</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-b5" class="">
        <span>Boards</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#nav-b6" class="">
        <span>Boards</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё раз спасибо пока ждал, нашел решение. Правда не совсем то что я хотел. Но тоже работает. Якоря меняются меняются при скролле мышкой, все работает. Один момент, пришлось ставить jquery 2.2.1 в остальном все работает на ура.

```
var menu_selector = ".dot-nav"; 

function onScroll(){
var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
$(menu_selector + " a").each(function(){
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);
    if (target.position().top <= scroll_top && target.position().top + 
    target.outerHeight() > scroll_top) {
        $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

$("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).off("scroll");
    $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var hash = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(hash);

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 500, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

});
```